# Validate Input in yyyy/mm/dd Format Using C

Tags: c

I want to check if the the buffer contains input that follows **yyyy/mm/dd** format.
The issue I am having is figuring out how to check if there are '/' in the input.

Here is some sample code of what I had before

```
bool age_is_valid(const char* buffer){
    if (buffer == NULL) 
        return false;
    const int len = strnlen(buffer, 1024);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // return true if the buffer contains any alphabetical characters or spaces
        if (isalpha(buffer[i]) && isspace(buffer[i])) 
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I have tried changing the `if` statement to:

```
if (isalpha(buffer[i]) && isspace(buffer[i]) && !buffer[4] == '/' && !buffer[7] == '/') 
        return false;
```

This would check if the 5th and 8th elements of the buffer are '/', however, it does not work. I have also tried using `isupper()` and `islower()` rather than `isalpha()`, but still no luck.

Comment: Your logic seems flawed.  When i == 0, you can't `return true` because you still need to validate the character in `buffer[1]`.  Typically, this sort of thing is done by iterating over the characters and only returning false if one of the the characters is bad.  If you get to the end of the loop without returning false, then you return true.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I see what you mean, however, this function works the way I intend it to in my program. I am trying to improve it so that it works for the **yyyy/mm/dd** format as well. Nonetheless, I have changed the return values so that there are no logic flaws just for this block of code.

Answer (score 2):

To check for `yyyy/mm/dd`, code could pedantically apply `sscanf()`.

```
// scanf for 1 and only 1 digit character. Do not save.
#define D10 "%*1[0-9]"

bool age_is_valid(const char* buffer){
  if (buffer == NULL) return false;  // Invalid argument

  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buffer, D10 D10 D10 D10 "/" D10 D10 "/" D10 D10 "%n", &n);
  // If scan incomplete or junk at the end ...
  if (n == 0 || buffer[n]) return false;  // Format error

  int y,m,d;
  sscanf(buffer, "%d/%d/%d", &y, &m, &d);
  if ((y < YEAR_MIN || y > YEAR_MAX) ||
      (m < 1 || m > 12) ||
      (d < 1 || d > dom(y,m)) return false;  // Range error
  return true;
}
```

A more efficient test would use a series of `isdigit()` calls.

Comment: @DevSolar Fixed, and fixed.  I'll talk to the proofreader team about their sloppy work.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution to your problem would be to iterate over each character of the buffer and do a separate check for the 5th and 8th character:

```c
bool date_is_valid(const char* buffer){
    if (buffer == NULL){
        return false;
    }

    const int len = strlen(buffer);
    
    // check number of characters - yyyy/mm/dd is 10 chars
    if(len != 10){
        return false;
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
        // for 5th and 8th character check if they are equal to '/'
        if(i == 4 || i == 7){
            if(buffer[i] != '/'){
                return false;
            }
        }
        // for all other characters check if they are valid digits
        else{
            if (!isdigit((unsigned char) buffer[i])){
                 return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that this kind of test would not validate if date values are in correct ranges.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for feedback, you are right - fixed!

Comment: Hmm, down stream from my ggfather home of Opole - Na Zdrowie